# Looking for windows event viewer system logs message templates , where can I get them?

Tags: windows, event-log, event-viewer

I need to get hold of at least microsoft windows system events message templates , 
is there a place I can find those?

a template for example :

Windows cannot access the file gpt.ini for GPO CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=,DC=com. The file must be present at the location <\\sysvol\\Policies{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini>. (.). Group Policy processing aborted.

where the parameters are surrounded by tags.

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Each event log in windows has it own registry entry, for example:

`System` event log has it entry at this path: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Security`

Under `System` key there are keys for each event source, that writes events into `System` event log.
Most of event sources also contain `EventMessageFile` value, which points you to a .dll or .exe that contain [Message Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) inside it. That's actually yyou should look for. It would be useful to read about [Event Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows.

Also there are some tools already, that allows you to see messages for a particular event source, unfortunately, I don't remember exact names of that utilities.